# Number of points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: finite-fields, projective-space, combinatorial-geometry

$\mathbb{P}^n = \mathbb{A}^{n}⊔\mathbb{A}^{n-1}⊔\mathbb{A}^{n-2}⊔...⊔ \mathbb{A}^{2}⊔\mathbb{A}^{1}⊔\mathbb{A}^{0} $

Use this decomposition to give a formula for the number of points of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a prime number.

Is the number of points $= p^n + p^{n-1} + p^{n-2} +...+ p^2 +p^1 +p^0$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: (There is no such thing as $F_n$, though)